# Automatic Date Entered after userform data entered

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Is there a way I can automate the date or time once the I enter the data from the User_Form via "enter/click" button? I've tried this code but it keeps restarting my excel workbook. On top of that, I have a ton of other codes in the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Is it possible it's overloaded ?

So I'm thinking if I could code it with my Userform_click() I'd be better off?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 16 To 100 
    If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Date & " " 
        Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your handler is recursive, and there's no way out. The handler runs every time a cell changes, and it changes cells, which runs the handler again, which changes cells, which runs the handler again, which... which eventually blows the call stack and sends everything up in flames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the beginning of your `Sub`, otherwise it will keep running it every time a value is changed inside the worksheet (like when you change it inside your `For i = 16 To 100` loop).

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False

For i = 16 To 100
    If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Date & " "
        Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
    End If
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True '<-- restore to original setting

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 1**: You can write your `Sub` in another way, that it will enter it only if a cell is changed inside the searched `Range("C16:C100")`. Only if the modified cell is inside that range, then check each cell if the `Value <> ""`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim C As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Range("C16:C100"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    For Each C In Intersect(Range("C16:C100"), Target)
        If C.Value <> "" Then
            C.Offset(, -2).Value = Date & " "
            C.Offset(, -2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        End If
    Next C
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```